# Deploy rails 3.2 app fails with capistrano filename too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

Needs help to solve fails capistrano deploy proccess.

We attempt to deploy our app with capistrano and it fails with cash error

GemFile look like this

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'haml'
gem 'rake', '10.0.3'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'russian'
gem 'kaminari'
gem "rails-settings-cached"
gem 'devise'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'enumerize'
gem 'rack-cache', :require => 'rack/cache'
gem 'dragonfly', '~> 0.9.12'
gem 'imperavi-rails', :github => 'Paxa/imperavi-rails', :ref => 'ec989856'
gem 'awesome_nested_set'
gem 'exception_notification', '2.6.1'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'therubyracer', '0.10.2', :platforms => :ruby
end
gem 'right-rails'
group :development do
  gem 'hipchat'
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano_colors'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano'
end
group :production do
  gem 'thin'
end
```

[image]

In last commit was add right-dialog js and css

How can we fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: It's look like a cache file, have you tried cleaning the tmp? `rake tmp:clear`

Comment: Sory late response and thanks for replay Edu Lomeli, but this not helped. We steel don't know how to fix

Comment: @edu-lomeli have you any idea?

Comment: I analyzed deeply your Gemfile, and maybe is an issue with `rack-cache` and `dragonfly`, take a look to [this guide](http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/rails/#caching) it may help to modify the cached filename

Comment: Thanks to you Edu Lomeli(@edu-lomeli)! We'll look to guid, which you refer. Thanks again